# Center binary tree with css or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**TRANSLATED:**

I need to centralize this binary tree with css or js .

Jquery is an available option.

The html code will be generated by php script nested array format.

I have created this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aymone/xajh4qwb/) for help.

thanks in advance

Html:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='root node'>
        <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
        <p>root name</p>
        <p>150</p>
        <div class='lft'>
            <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
            <p>lft name</p>
            <p>200</p>
            <div class='node'>
                <div class='lft'>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                    <p>lft name</p>
                    <p>100</p>
                    <div class='lft'>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                        <p>lft name</p>
                        <p>200</p>
                        <div class='node'>
                            <div class='lft'>
                                <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                                <p>lft name</p>
                                <p>50</p>
                                <div class='lft'>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                                    <p>lft name</p>
                                    <p>50</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class='rgt'>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                                    <p>rgt name</p>
                                    <p>100</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class='rgt'>
                                <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                                <p>rgt name</p>
                                <p>150</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='rgt'>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                        <p>rgt name</p>
                        <p>50</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='rgt'>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                    <p>rgt name</p>
                    <p>0</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='rgt'>
            <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
            <p>rgt name</p>
            <p>100</p>
            <div class='node'>
                <div class='lft'>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                    <p>lft name</p>
                    <p>50</p>
                </div>
                <div class='rgt'>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                    <p>rgt name</p>
                    <p>100</p>
                    <div class='node'>
                        <div class='lft'>
                            <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                            <p>lft name</p>
                            <p>50</p>
                            <div class='lft'>
                                <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                                <p>lft name</p>
                                <p>150</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class='rgt'>
                                <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                                <p>rgt name</p>
                                <p>200</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='rgt'>
                            <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i></p>
                            <p>rgt name</p>
                            <p>50</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.root {
position: absolute !important;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow-x: auto;
display:block;
text-align:center;
background-color: #ddd;
}
.node {
width: auto;
height:auto;
}
.lft, .rgt {
margin:5px;
margin-top: 20px;
min-width:60px;
min-height:60px;
position:relative;
}
.rgt {
border:1px solid #000;
float:right;
background-color: #ccc;
}
.lft {
border:1px solid #fff;
float:left;
background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution may help you. It's using css3 (no javascript) to draw a simple binary tree. Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9zftw6o1/) and a [step by step tutorial](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)

**HTML:**

```
<!--
We will create a family tree using just CSS(3)
The markup will be simple nested lists
-->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
    display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
    border-color:  #94a0b4;
}

/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```